# Creating objects on the heap through a class function

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, allocation

```
   Book book;
list<Book>* books;

string title;
string author;
int ISBN;

     Book* Administrator::addBook()
{
    Book *newBook = new Book();
    cout << "Would you like to enter a book?" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
    cout << endl;

    if (userInput == "yes")
    {

        cout << "What is the title of the book you want to enter?" << endl;
        cin >> title;

        cout << "What is the author of the book you want to enter?" << endl;
        cin >> author;

        cout << "What is the ISBN of the book you want to enter?" << endl;
        cin >> ISBN;

        cout << endl;

        newBook->setTitle(title);
        newBook->setAuthor(author);
        newBook->setISBN(ISBN);
        newBook->setAvailability(true);

        books->push_back(*newBook);

    }
    return newBook;
}
```

Here im creating my book objects in my `Administration` class, the problem im having is when i try and access them from another class, its says they are not there.

I did a bit of reading and understand I've to allocate the objects to the heap using dynamic memory management, is there a way i can do this within my code?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think this is creating anything on the heap?

Comment: No, sorry, i want to add them on the heap, my code is not currently doing that

Comment: Gotcha. See sample below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to gain access to a list of objects thats in another class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180609/how-to-gain-access-to-a-list-of-objects-thats-in-another-class)

Comment: If you need a variable to perform an operation in a method, such as `book` in `addBook`, please declare it in that method, not as a class member or globally. This will make the lifetime of the object clear to the reader, and also signal that there is no intention for the object to be shared between `addBook` invocations. A true shared member, such as `books`, should of course remain a member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
if (userInput == "yes")
{
   Book *newBook = new Book(); // <-- allocates a Book object on the heap
   cout << "What is the title of the book you want to enter?" << endl;
   [...]
   newBook->setTitle(title);
   [...]
   return *newBook;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, just another quick question, I've now made my `list<Book> books` a pointer to hold all my books but im now getting an accessing violation reading location. I've updated the code to what i have now, do you know why this might be?

Comment: @user2757842 You need `list<Book*> books`, not `list<Book> *books`. The two are not the same. You are getting an access violation because `books` is a pointer and you're not allocating it. On the other hand, you are throwing away the heap-allocated `Book *` and assigning it to the instance allocated as part of the list.

Comment: @user2757842 For further unrelated questions about a specific problem, you probably want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

you have to decide if you want to use the `book` that is in your class, or create a different book, or a heap copy of your book

if you want a different book you will need to use the `new` operator at the start

if you want to create a copy of your book on the heap:

`return new Book(book)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Book* Administrator::addBook()
{
    Book *bookOnHeap = new Book();
    ....
    return bookOnHeap;
}
```

Comment: That should be `return bookOnHeap;`, no?

Comment: Your return is of type Book. Should be Book*. return bookOnHeap; would correct ( i.e also () is wrong).